# What is the best way to renew azure authentication automatically?

Tags: c#, azure, server, azure-active-directory

I have a local server exposing an api that let clients to interface with some azure APIs such as azure ressource manager .

The authentication is done using the **Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory** nugget package. I get a token and use that token to make requests to those APIs.

The problem is that this token expires after after a certain period and the clients can no more access azure APIs services through the local server.

Is there a way or best practice that allows the local server to automatically reauthenticate or acquire a new token.

The goal is to automate this such as connectivity with azure api is available all the time for consumption through the local server.

Any help or guidance will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to automatically reauthenticate or acquire a new token when the previous token expires. When the token expires, you could use refresh_token to get a new token. Or you could Configurable token lifetimes, the maximum for the access_token lifetime is 1 day. For the details about configuring token lifetime, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

Comment: Yeah, using refresh tokens is the way to do it. ADAL / MSAL handle those for you, though you must make sure you have a proper token cache specified. By default the cache is just in-memory so can be lost on app restarts etc.

Comment: Please, do you have any practical example demonstrating this.